# Strange issue with 'subset'

Tags: r, subset

I have a strange issue with `subset`: it doesn't recognize the variables in my dataframe.

For example, if I want a summary of the variable `v1` in the dataframe `DF`, I get:

```
summary(DF$v1)

 Min.    1st Qu. Median  Mean   3rd Qu. Max
-123.00  4.00    14.00   84.62  49.00   13140.00
```

Now, this variable should always be non-negative, so I want to inspect the negative values by subsetting the dataframe `DF` into the dataframe `PROBS`. But if I try this:

```
PROB <- subset[DF, v1 < 0]
```

I get:

```
Error: object "v1" not found
```

I am positive that I am not misspelling this variable name. I have tried with other variables in this dataframe, but it keeps throwing this error at me.

Does anyone have any idea about the reason for such a strange behaviour? I have never had any problem with the `subset` function!

Thanks.

Comment: Don't use square brackets, but parentheses, i.e. `subset(DF, v1 <0)`

Comment: Gosh, the devil really _is_ in the details! Thanks and sorry for the dumb question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Subset is a function, so you should use `subset(DF, v1 < 0)` instead of the square brackets.

Square brackets are used for subsetting dataframes or matrices directly. `subset[DF, v1 < 0]` is trying to subset the `subset` function by looking for the variable `v1` within the scope of the `subset` object. The object `subset` is a function, so it can't find the `v1` object.

Comment: Ironically, the function `subset` and the function `[` (see `?"["`) actually do the same thing with almost identical syntax and arguments!

Comment: One caveat is that "Note that ‘subset’ will be evaluated in the data frame, so columns can be referred to (by name) as variables in the expression (see the examples)."